# Pattern for managing multiple reducers inside of a module [Redux]

Tags: reactjs, directory, redux, file-structure, directory-structure

I am new to Redux and am trying to figure out a scaleable way to setup my projects folder/file structure.

Lets say we have a file structure that looks like this:

> root/modules/Todos/reducers

In the root of the project there lives a 'rootReducer.js' file which utilizes 'combineReducers()' to create a top-level implementation of the state tree:

```
[rootReducer.js]

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import todos from './modules/Todos/reducers/index.js';

export default combineReducers({
  todos: todos
});
```

Inside of the 'reducers' folder for each module there are multiple reducers:

```
[root/modules/Todos/reducers]

>index.js
>Todos__addItem
>Todos__removeItem
```

The 'index.js' file imports all of the reducers for that module and exports a single object:

```
[index.js]

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import addItem from './Todos__addItem.js';
import removeItem from './Todos__removeItem.js';

export default const todos = combineReducers({
  addItem: addItem,
  removeItem: removeItem
});
```

Is this the correct use of 'combineReducers()'?

Does this pattern make sense when developing a large scale application?

What are (if any) potential pitfalls that come along with this pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/suin/redux-multiple-reducers-example .   EXAMPLE!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not the correct usage of `combineReducers`.  `combineReducers` is used to delegate management of a specific slice of state to a given function.  Your example would actually create slices of state named `addItem` and `removeItem`, when what you really want to do is to update the same `todos` slice of state using those functions in different ways depending on which action was dispatched.

The Redux docs section on ["Structuring Reducers"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/structuring-reducers) has some information that should help with this, including the section on [Using `combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers).

Comment: I appreciate the reply and work you've done with your writings! In regards to the 'export todos' statement in 'index.js', do you know how I might refactor that to achieve what I am looking for? I'm having troubles figuring out the right way to implement it! Should I be exporting the collection of sub-reducers as a function, or just a plain object?

Comment: The `todo` handling would be where you'd see the typical switch statement or lookup table for the various update cases.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers for a relevant example. Also, in case you haven't seen them yet, Dan has two great video tutorial series where he demonstrates a number of reducer approaches: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux and https://egghead.io/series/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux .

Answer (score 0):

example from https://github.com/suin/redux-multiple-reducers-example

```
import   {counter1, counter2 } from "../../reducers/index"
import CounterApp from "../containers/CounterApp";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  one:counter1 ,
  two:counter2
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

class App extends  React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <CounterApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

Counter1 view

```
import * as counter1Actions from "../../actions/counter1Actions";

@connect(state => ({
  counter1: state.one
}))
export default class Counter1 extends  React.Component{

  static propTypes = {
    counter1: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.info("counter1 component did mount.");
  }

  onClick() {
    console.info("counter1 button was clicked.");
    const action = bindActionCreators(counter1Actions, this.props.dispatch);
    action.increment();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter 1</h1>
        <button onClick={::this.onClick}>increment</button>
        <div>Total: <span>{this.props.counter1}</span></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Counter2 view

```
import * as counter2Actions from "../../actions/counter2Actions";

@connect(state => ({
  counter2: state.two
}))
export default class Counter2 extends  React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    counter2: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.info("counter2 component did mount.");
  }

  onClick() {
    console.info("counter2 button was clicked.");
    const action = bindActionCreators(counter2Actions, this.props.dispatch);
    action.increment();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter 2</h1>
        <button onClick={::this.onClick}>increment</button>
        <div>Total: <span>{this.props.counter2}</span></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CounterApp**

```
import Counter1 from "../components/Counter1";
import Counter2 from "../components/Counter2";

 class CounterApp extends  React.Component{
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Counter1/>
         <Counter2/>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

reducer

```
export default function counter1(state = initialState, event) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case "COUNTER1_INCREMENTED":
      console.info(`counter1 ack ${event.type}: event =`, event);
      return state + 1;
    default:
      console.warn("counter1 ack unknown event: state =", state, "event =", event);
      return state;
  }

export default function counter2(state: Object = initialState, event: Object): Object {
  switch (event.type) {
    case "COUNTER2_INCREMENTED":
      console.info(`counter2 ack ${event.type}: event =`, event);
      return state + 1;
    default:
      console.warn("counter2 ack unknown event: state =", state, "event =", event);
      return state;
  }
}
```